# Generating Live Time In Textbox only works at page refreshment

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a textbox that generates current datetime and a updatepanel and timer control to generate time at each seconds.

However, my textbox is generating seconds at page refreshment only not at each seconds.

**This is the code for timer:**

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="true"></asp:Timer>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

       txtTransDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    }

}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTransDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: Did you set an interval for the timer ?

Comment: No, How to set interval.

Comment: `Interval="1000"` you might want to check an example out in  this [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx)